# Method Arguments(className and method name) in jvm profiler

Tags: java, jvm

I am creating an java agent to capture the method name and classname but not getting the way to do. I have to make a jar of that agent and insert in some sample project to check the captured data.

Comment: What kind of help you need?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: I mean I know how to get class name and method name But where to implement so that agent can capture

Comment: @Andy This is the example to get the data. I have to put this data in Map for all which present on sample project

Comment: `public class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Test t1 = new Test();
 
    Class cls = t1.getClass();
 
    System.out.println("cls: " + cls);                      // prints class Test  
    System.out.println("cls.getName(): " + cls.getName());  // prints Test
  }
}`

Comment: @amit lodihi  if  you use java -jar method to start you application,you can add -javaagent:path then start your application. cat more usefull info [javaagent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions, I don't know if it helps you.Use `Instrumentation API` supported by JVM to capture classes loaded by JVM is easy.First，create a class which implements `ClassFileTransformer` interface and override the only method `transform`，the second parameter of method is the class name of loaded class by JVM，the format of name like`io/github/YourAgent`，so get the class name is very directl. Second,the interface also give a manipulate the class bytecode，you can try.

```
    @Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
        System.out.println("load class " + className);
        return classfileBuffer;
    }
```